# unable to post in a custom field in Wordpress

Tags: python, json, wordpress

This is my first time posting here and I appreciate all the help and input that I can get.

I'm using python to automate my posts to a WordPress theme that I purchased (Newspaper by tagDiv).

I'm using the json/Rest API to communicate with the webpage.
In the template that I'm working on there is a custom field that is called "Featured Audio". Through Python, I'm trying to post a value to this field but I'm unable to do that. Any suggestion on how I can find the correct name of that field.

```
post = {
    'title': 'Sample Title',
    'status': 'publish', 
    "content": 'Sample text',
    'featured_audio': {'href': 'www.example.com/hello.mp3'}
    }
        
r = requests.post(url + '/posts', headers=header, json=post)

print(r)
```

[image: Screenshot from post-page]

thnx in advance guys!

Comment: Have you read a documentation of the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#schema-featured_media)?

Comment: I did but was unable to find anything of help...could be mainly bcz this is a custom field and one that is not exposed to Rest API